# Why would validator take my old error message and not the new error message?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am using MVC5, which contains a form with the following fields:

```
StudentType - Radio button
GradId - dropdown
HSYearofGradId - dropdown
CollegeStatusId - dropdown
```

With those fields, I want to apply a validation rule on `HSYearofGradId`, based on what they select. For example if they select a `StudentType` **A**, they will only see `GradId` and only if they select the third item in `GradId` they will see `HSYearofGradId`. Similarly if they select `StudentType` **B**, then they see both `GradId` and `HSYearofGradId`. The key here is that `StudentType` **A** and **B** are different, so the error message should show a different value.

I have the following error message: `You must select an option for your year of {0} in order to proceed."` I want to replace the {0} with a value on the client side.

After stepping through the JavaScript, I noticed that my string was being replaced at first, but then it was being overridden by the original error I set: `You must select an option for your year of {0} in order to proceed. I noticed this in one validator's internals:`$.validator.format(message.replace(theregex, "{$1}"), rule.parameters);` which changes the {0} into [object object].

I was using the following question as reference:
[How to change MVC custom client-side validation error message at runtime using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008631/how-to-change-mvc-custom-client-side-validation-error-message-at-runtime-using-j/23009749?noredirect=1#comment36839292_23009749)

So, I used MVC's unobtrusive client side validation feature. I made a custom validation attribute, implementing the IClientValidatable interface. The GetClientValidationRules method looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var modelClientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "requiredif",
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage
        };

        // rule.ValidationParameters["condition"] = "#" + Condition; // CSS Selector (won't work if applied to nested properties on a viewmodel)

        // Attached to field
        modelClientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("property", Property);
        modelClientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("condition", Condition);
        modelClientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("minimum", Minimum);
        modelClientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("errormessage", ErrorMessage);

        yield return modelClientValidationRule;
    }
```

This validation attribute is applied on the following properties like this:

```
        [Display(Name = "College Student Status")]
        [Integer(ErrorMessage = "You must select an option for College Student Status in order to proceed.")]
        [RequiredIf("StudentType", "college", 1, ErrorMessage = "You must select an option for College Student Status in order to proceed.")]
        public Nullable<int> CollegeStatusId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "When will you graduate?")]
        [Integer(ErrorMessage = "You must select an option for when will you graduate in order to proceed.")]
        [RequiredIf("StudentType", "high school", 1, ErrorMessage = "You must select an option for when will you graduate in order to proceed.")]
        public Nullable<int> GradId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HS Year")]
        public string HighSchoolYear { get; set; }

        // Choosing 3rd option for gradId
        [Display(Name = "In which year did you graduate?")]
        [Integer(ErrorMessage = "You must select an option for your year of graduation to proceed.")]
        [RequiredIf("StudentType", "3", 1, ErrorMessage = "You must select an option for your year of {0} in order to proceed.")]
        public Nullable<int> HSYearofGradId { get; set; }
```

I have the client side validation functions in a .js file, which looks like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('requiredif', function (value, element, params) {
var validator = this;
var conditionIsMet = false;
var propertyId = $(element).attr('data-val-requiredif-property');
var condition = $(element).attr('data-val-requiredif-condition');
var minimum = $(element).attr('data-val-requiredif-minimum');
var errorMessage = $(element).attr('data-val-requiredif-errormessage');
var errors = {};
var radioValue = $("input[name='" + propertyId + "']:checked").val();

if (propertyId === "StudentType") {

    // i.e. high school
    if (radioValue === condition) {
        conditionIsMet = true;
    }
}
else if (propertyId === "HighSchoolLocal") {
    // what if not dropdown
    if (value === "") {

        // check if we are in no mode.
        if (radioValue === condition) {
            conditionIsMet = false;
        } else {

            if ($('#LocalBoroughId').is(':disabled')) {
                conditionIsMet = false;
            } else {
               conditionIsMet = true; 
            }
        }
    }
}

//TODO: hardcoded value
if (element.id === "HSYearofGradId") {
    if (parseInt($(element).val()) < parseInt(minimum)) {
        var gradType;

        if (radioValue === 'college') {

            // TODO: error message is still wrong
            gradType = "High School graduation";
        } else {
            gradType = "graduation";
        }

        errors[element.name] = $.validator.format(errorMessage, gradType);

        $.validator.messages.requiredif = $.validator.format(errorMessage, gradType);

        validator.showErrors(errors);

        conditionIsMet = false;
    } else {
        conditionIsMet = true;
    }

} else if (value) {
    if (parseInt(value) < parseInt(minimum)) {

        errors[element.name] = errorMessage;

        validator.showErrors(errors);
        conditionIsMet = false;
    } else {
        conditionIsMet = true;
    }
}

return conditionIsMet; });
```

Here is the adapter:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('requiredif', {}, function (options) {
options.rules['requiredif'] = options.params;

if (options.message != null) {
    options.messages['requiredif'] = options.message;
}});
```

**Edit:**
I think I found the issue. There are a few methods inside jquery.validate.js that will get me the custom message for the given element name and validation method. All the arguments are passed to the following method. I noticed that the first error on the list is passed back. Also, the first error happens to be the original error set on the entity.

```
findDefined: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            if ( arguments[i] !== undefined ) {
                return arguments[i];
            }
        }
```

- 0: "You must select an option for your year of High School graduation
  in order to proceed."
- 1: undefined
- 2: undefined
- 3: "You must select an option for your year of High School graduation in order to proceed."
- 4: "**Warning: No message defined for HSYearofGradId**"

**Temporary Solution:**

*I don't know if this is the best way, but it works.*

```
this.settings.messages["FIELDNAME"]["VALIDATION_NAME"] = "NEW MESSAGE"
```

In my case I did the following:

```
errors[element.name] = $.validator.format(errorMessage, gradType);

$.validator.messages.requiredif = $.validator.format(errorMessage, gradType);

this.settings.messages["HSYearofGradId"]["requiredif"] = $.validator.messages.requiredif;
```